# Does the color of a Command Card affect its Crit Star Gather Rate?

Tags: fate-grand-order

In Fate/Grand Order, the distribution of Crit Stars is affected by the Crit Star Gather Rate (also known as "Star Absorbtion" to JP players) of individual servants. For instance, Osakabehime has a Gather Rate of 102, while Minamoto-no-Raikou only has 9.

However, I noticed that Buster cards seemingly get fewer Crit Stars than other cards. Is this just my imagination? Or is there a hidden multiplier for each card type, making it more likely for a Crit Star to land on a Quick card than, for instance, a Buster card?

Or, to phrase it succinctly: Does the color of a Command Card affect its Crit Star Gather Rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did about 50 test runs myself and it seems that **card color has no effect on crit star gather rate**.

The only thing affecting CSGR were:

- Servant's inherent CSGR
- Command Codes affecting CSGR (Armament of Triumph, Immature Illusionary Command Seal, etc.)
- Servant Skills (Genji-clan Martial Arts Discipline EX, etc.)
- Craft Essences (Sealing Designation Enforcer, Starlight Fest, etc.)

Comment: I am aware that 50 is comparatively low, but given that each attempt cost me AP to perform, I had to cut a limit somewhere. Besides, the likelihood of CS distribution randomly appearing as if it were not affected by card color, when in reality it is affected, for 50 attempts nonetheless, is rather small.